# How can I track data for individual users of my mobile app without having them login?

Tags: analytics, backend

I'd like to manage user data (i.e. number of coins they've collected) for a mobile game I'm creating without forcing them to login to anything.  In other words, I want my app to send game stats to my backend server to store in a database and I want those game stats to be associated with some kind of unique ID.  What are some ways I can do this?

A couple ideas I had were...
1) Use the UDID for the mobile device
2) Use the MAC address of the mobile device (but this seems difficult to access in some APIs)

Your thoughts?

I did a quick search on both Google and SO, but could find much.  Thanks so much in advance for you wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not ask the server for a globally unique ID and then store it on the device, like a cookie?

Comment: How to ensure that this will be secure? That other person cannot change the user data?

Comment: Would you please post a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't track device hardware IDs because the phone might be sold to someone else that later installs your game and you're in trouble. It's usually recommended practice to track "installation" ids (and then use it to identify a particular player of your app if you're not using logins). For more info see this awesome blog post by the Android team (Android code snippet included):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html